# Making textbox color red when error occurs in a form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I need your help.. I'm trying to make the textbox red whenever there's an error in a form...

This is what i've being able to do. But when i submit the fore, I get an Undefined Index **error_css** in the form

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
       $error_css='background-color:red';
 }
```

**Form**

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" name="username" title='Username' />
```

thanks for your time...

Comment: What's up with the massive space between `</` and `label>`?  Also, please post **all** of your code.

Comment: User, I added the `id="username"` just cause I see you use the same label for, and you've been missing that. `FOR` is a reference to a form element `ID`

Comment: @user1378680 Please post of the rest of your code; preferably, the part that actually calls your $error_css variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$username = "";
$error_css = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    else
        $error_css='background-color:red';
}

?>

<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name="username" title='Username' style="<?php echo $error_css; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$error_css` is empty/does not exist.

I think the 2 if cases in the beginning of your script never reach the point where `$error_css` gets its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, why not look into a solution like [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)? It's not a complete solution, as you still need some sort of server side validation, but it'll get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Form

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input id="username" type="text" value="<?php echo @$_POST['username']; ?>"
   name="username" title='Username' style="<?php echo @$error_css; ?>"/>
```

Comment: ;) was there to shorten the code. The approach is hopeless, so I thought that could also be slid in.

Comment: I would +1 this if you added the `ID` referenced by the label `for`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - There! ... just kidding, thanks for pointing the omission.

Comment: The `for` is used in reference to the `name` not `id`

Comment: @user1378680 - what do you get back from PHP?

Comment: Majid... Thanks for the answer, but you word is awful.. Cant you help without passing insults. I wonder if it's a crime to ask questions...

Comment: @user1378680 - What have I said that has insulted you? I fail to see anything remotely resembling one.

Comment: Oh, you mean my remark about the approach? Sorry man - no offence intended, but apparently some taken ;)

Answer (score 0):

you never set the style in the html tag and the first if{if{}} statements are redundant. It should be:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) { 
            echo 'value="'.$_POST['username'].'"'; 
        } else {
            echo 'style="background-color:red"';
        }
    ?> name="username" title='Username' >
```

Comment: Does not actually work it just prints out style="background-color:red" on the screen....

Comment: @Yunfei Chen you are mistaken, this does work. Copy and paste this exact script and you will see it does work.