# Displaying differnt border color if field is valid

Tags: php, html, css, forms

So I have my form which I have supplied pictures of below. The left side picture is a normal border color but then the red outline on the right is when the form input is invalid.

[image]
[image]

How would I do this through PHP? Here's the corresponding code

```
<?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=s','root', '*');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

// Post
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];   
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$password1 = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Verifcation 
if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($password1)) {
    echo "Complete all fields";
}

// Password match
if ($password != $password1) {
    echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
}

// Email validation
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
}

// Password length
if (strlen($password) <= 6){
    echo $passlength = "Choose a password longer then 6 character";
}

if(empty($passmatch) && empty($emailvalid) && empty($passlength)) { 
//Securly insert into database
$sql = 'INSERT INTO userinfo (name ,username, email, password, ip) VALUES (:name,:username,:email,:password,:ip)';

$query = $handler->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':username' => $username,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $password,
    ':ip' => $ip

 ));
}
?>
```

And my HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">        
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="register.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"  name="name" autofocus style="border-color:#<?php   ?>;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  name="username" autofocus>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"  name="email" autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password, Again" name="passwordconf" >
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So if the input satisfies the if statement how would I display the color?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? For the classes you are using, it's seems so: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation You have to add the corresponding class to the input.

Comment: Yeah I'm using bootstrap @azeós

Comment: you could use a flash session and appoint an error class, then if that flash session error is set, echo it on the particular field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making textbox color red when error occurs in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626160/making-textbox-color-red-when-error-occurs-in-a-form)

Comment: I wouldn't say its a duplicate since everyones code varies @DanMan

Comment: @Colourity: It's the same problem: highlight error in form. Doesn't matter if it's the border or the text.

Comment: Well thats a solely PHP way, the answers also include JS ways, which could be helpful to other users also @DanMan

Comment: @Colourity: I don't want to argue. The answers don't matter. The questions are the same. Neither asked for a JS solution - look at the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your form has errors, you need to re-display it. It's hard to give a recommendation without knowing your code structure, but I will assume that your HTML is rendered via a call to php. Generally, I have done something like

```
$error = false
//this $_GET['submit'] variable could be part of the URL of your submitted form.
//alternately, you could check the HTTP method of the page request
if ($_GET['submit']) {
    //run your form logic
    //if you have success, run your php query and then redirect
    //to your "success" page using a 302 (using a header("Location:... sort of call)
    //you would also want to call die() or something right here
}
//if you make it this far, display your page including the bits about errors
//your form's action goes right back to the same page that rendered it, but with
//some change to the url to let the script know that you want to process the form
```

With PHP5 and with warnings about undefined variables turned on, you would need to define all of your error message variables before checking whether or not the form is being submitted.

Asuming you are using twitter bootstrap since you have `form-control` all over the place,  (assuming >= 3.0.0), you can use (for the graphical side of things) `has-suceess`, `has-error`, etc like shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation.

When you re-display the form due to bad data, pass along your error messages to whatever renders your html. An example with your thing would be (assuming your form has access to `$passmatch`, `$emailvalid`,`$passlength`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">        
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="register.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"  name="name" autofocus style="border-color:#<?php   ?>;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  name="username" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php if (!empty($emailvalid)) { echo 'has-error'; } ?>">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"  name="email" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php if (!empty($passmatch) || !empty($passlength)) { echo 'has-error'; } ?>">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php if (!empty($passmatch)) { echo 'has-error'; } ?>">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password, Again" name="passwordconf" >
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I would recommend using a templating engine or something to separate the view from the actual code.

As for the help text, you can use something like this after the elements with errors:

```
<div class="form-group <?php if (!empty($yourVariable)) { echo 'has-error'; }?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $yourVariable; ?></span>
</div>
```

The fun part is, if you have no error message, the help block won't even be shown because that variable won't have anything in it.

**EDIT**

Example page: http://content.kevincuzner.com/register.php

Example source: https://gist.github.com/kcuzner/11323907

Comment: Is your HTML just a static page or is it created by PHP? If it is not created by PHP, my HTML will not work since it has PHP stuff intermixed with the HTML.

Comment: Its just a simple sign up form but its a PHP file.

Comment: What I was trying to communicate in my answer was that I would combine both your signup form and your `register.php` into the same php file. That way, before you submit the form, it renders the php. After submission, the same script runs again and tries to create the user. If success, it redirects to some success page. If failure, it display the same form over again.

Comment: I didn't test my HTML, so are there any errors when you try to load it? Its very likely I made a syntax error or something.

Comment: Ok, my syntax errors are fixed (I had a couple trailing `)`). It should at least load now.

Comment: So `action` would be taking me to the page I want users to go to, after I insert info into the database through my one file?

Comment: Also when I submit it takes me to `register.php` and displays the errors there....

Comment: Not quite. When I said action I was referring to the form action attribute. A user goes to `http://yoursite/register.php` and is shown the form (no registration logic taken since `$_GET['submit']` is not defined). Your form has `<form action="register.php?submit=true" method="POST">...</form>` in it. They submit the form. Your register.php sees `$_GET['submit']` and either redirects them (for example) to `success.php` (on success) or continue on and display the form again, this time with your error messages.

Comment: Sorry for being difficult to cope with. But the errors _still_ show on `register.php`....

Comment: Ok. Here is the page: http://content.kevincuzner.com/register.php. Here is the php: https://gist.github.com/kcuzner/11323907

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this on the client side with JavaScript.  On submission of the form, you can check whether the input is valid or not and then just update the border color using JavaScript.

The `<?php ?>` you can fill in above (if you want to go this route) can just depend on some variable that checks validity:

```
echo "Complete all fields";
$fieldsValid = false;

border-color: <?php $fieldsValid ? 'blue' : 'red' ?>
```

But you need to do a full page reload for this to work.  JavaScript is a better route:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function () {
    var usernameInput = document.querySelector("[name=username]");
    if (!usernameInput.value) {
        usernameInput.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
});
```

Comment: So client side and serverside? And also how would that look in _my_ code? I'm fairly new with JS and I need all the help I can get!

Comment: It's bad practice to put the styles directly into the HTML. Set a CSS class like `error` on invalid fields and then put the styles in the stylesheet.