# Change background color of input if data is wrong

Tags: php, jquery, css, forms

I want to dynamically change background of input text when the entered data is wrong.

This is my TextField:

```
$oForm->formInput(array(
    'id' => 'phone',
    'name' => 'phone',
    'label' => 'telefon',
    'value' => $_POST['phone'],
    'type' => 'tel',
    'size' => '60',
    'maxlength'=>'30',
));
```

This is a function to check if entered data is correct.

```
function checkIfError($field){
    global $oForm;    

    if($_POST["ACT"] == 'checkCorrectness'){
        global $wrong;
        .
        .
        .
        case "phone":
                if(empty($_POST['phone'])){                       
                  <THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT>
                }else
                  <THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT>
                }
                break;
      }
}
```

But id doesn't work. Is it correct place to entered JavaScript code? Because even alert doesn't work.

For example if I entered the correct number input text should be white. If no input text should be green. I read about it and tried some JavaScript code but for now none of this didn't work. Can you help me?

**EDIT:**

In place  "THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT" in above code I created that:

```
echo '<script>         
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
                alert(phone);
                if (phone == ""){
                    $("#phone").css("background-color","yellow");
                }                               
 </script>';
```

I get an alert with text "undefined". The rest instruction in "if" doesn't work too.

Comment: Instead of showing the PHP code please show the created HTML markup and the JavaScript that you used.

Comment: You're right. I edited my post. HTML markup is in $oForm->formInput.

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your html

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="txt" value="Hello"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       var phone = $("#phone").val();
        if(phone === '')
        {
          $("#phone").css("background-color","yellow");
        }
        else
        {
          $("#phone").css("background-color","red");
        }
    });
    </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: It's good but I want to dynamically change color. Something like this:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/495/).
The problem is I want to change a color when the data will be incorrect. This is a place in <THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT> tag in above post. How can I properly make it?

Comment: you can use regular expressions to check the validity of the data and if your data has error you can set the background color of the textbox to red.

Comment: do you want the textbox to show error(red background) while the user is typing or once the user has finished typing into the text box

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, my english is not so good and i have some problems with explanations. I have a regular expression etc. but my problem is connections beetween php, html and javascript i think. Your code is good but how can i put it in <THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT> tag so it all worked?

Comment: i don't think you can do that, i mean javascript is used in html file or .js file only and not in controller or model files.

Comment: Look on my edited post. Mayby it will be more clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63864/discussion-between-robin-and-koin-arab).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is to add a class to the empty input field, for example add a class 'error'.

You could check the input fields with JQuery for example:

```
if('#yourInput').val() === '') {
  $('#yourInput').addClass('error');
}
```

And in your CSS:

```
.error {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: It looks good but i hava a problem with properly placing this in my code.

Comment: what problem in placing?

Comment: This could be a bit of help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312702/displaying-differnt-border-color-if-field-is-valid

Comment: @Robin 
I don't know exacly. I put it in <THIS IS A PLACE FOR JAVASCRIPT> tag from my post above but this doesn't work. Even if I created some alert.

Comment: just add the script in your html file or in another .js file and use it

Comment: You cant just mix PHP and JQuery, add it between <script> tags or in a .js file

Comment: I have it. Look on my edited post. Mayby it will be more clearly.